# highlight banners = recommend maximum of two, why?

Tags: dynamic-linking

I am trying to add highlight banners but while i do it within tridion window it states (recommend maximum of two) any reason? please suggest guys.

Comment: Please improve the quality of your question by providing details and steps you've tried to resolve.

Comment: This sounds like an implementation-specific question. Can you provide any screenshots to illustrate what's happening?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is implementation-specific, as defined in the help centre: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 5):

Whomever did your implementation of Tridion decided that the design of your site would have this limitation of a maximum of two banners.

This is in no way a Tridion limitation, but an implementation choice. Unless someone here was involved in your implementation I strongly doubt you'll find the answer on this site. You should connect to the admin team on your side and try to figure out why only 2 banners should be used.